# if we know that $y + f(y)y + 1$ goes over all real numbers once and f is bijective, can we conclude that $f(y)y$ is constant?

Tags: functional-equations

yep, that's all I've got to say, we know surely that $y + yf(y)$ goes over all real numbers once as well, and that's about all I got.

Comment: Why do you think that $f(y)y$ would be constant? Also, does "$y+f(y)y+1$ goes over all real numbers once" mean exactly once or just at least once?

Comment: If $f(y)=\frac{k}{y}$, where $k$ is some constant, then $f$ cannot be bijective.

Comment: Choose your favorite bijection function $g(y)$ and set $ y + f(y)y+1 = g(y)$. Is $f(y) y = g(y) - 1 - y $ always a constant?

Comment: @CalvinLin my point was to give a hint that $f$ cannot be bijective. I wasn't suggesting a function.

Comment: @AnuragA Yes, I realized that after posting and editing, hence deleted the comment. Sorry!

Comment: @CalvinLin my favorite bijection function is $g(y) = y$, then $g(y) - 1 - y = y - 1 - y = -1$ and thus it is always a constant.

Comment: @11235 Great ,what about for any bijective function? Can you find one where it is not a constant?

Comment: alright, I was pulling your leg a bit, I admit, yep $g(y) = ay$ for any $a \ne 1$ is not constant